# Can i pass a reference from one function to another

Tags: c#, .net, reference, pass-by-reference

Here i have three functions; passing a reference from function 1 to function 2.So in function 2, `a` is a reference. Then why it is not allowed to pass this same reference to function 3? without using the keyword `ref`

**Function 1:**

```
public void funReadA()
 {
    double a=10;
    //read value for a
    funReadB(ref a);
 }
```

**Function 2 :**

```
 public void funReadB(ref double a)
   {
    double b = 25;
    a = 11;    
    // sum(a, b);this method call is not allowed
    sum(ref a, b);// why ref a is required? a is already a reference na?
   }
```

**Function 3:**

```
public double sum(ref double a,double b)
   {
       return a += b;
   }
```

Comment: `ref` is not a data type. It is not attached to the `a` variable. It is attached to the parameter's definition.

Comment: What do you mean by *not allowed*?

Comment: i have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ref` keyword on the call site is required mostly to make sure the person who wrote the calling code is aware that he is passing a reference, and so that the value could change.

It's not strictly necessary from a *programming language* point of view, but it's a good idea from a *programmer* point of view.